# How to know when should a webcam/phone camera refocus?

Tags: unity, camera, mobile

This is the code I use to display the camera's footage inside my app:

```
var cameraDevice = WebCamTexture.devices[0];
var cameraTexture = new WebCamTexture(cameraDevice.name);
rawImage.texture = cameraTexture;
cameraTexture.Play();
```

So far it has been working, even though I **didn't have auto focus** because I could just position my phone so the QR code will be in focus distance.

But now a friend told me that after 3 minutes of fiddling, he just couldn't find a distance where the QR code would be in focus. **It was never in focus**. Thus he couldn't scan the code at all.

So now I have to figure out how to implement an **auto focus** feature.

Suprisingly I couldn't really find a lot of things about this feature and the ones I found weren't really useful.

All I found is this, I added it to my init sequence (previously **autoFocusPoint** was **null**) but other than getting 5 log lines of `"Camera2: Setting manual focus point already started."`, nothing changed it seems.

```
if (cameraDevice.isAutoFocusPointSupported)
{
     cameraTexture.autoFocusPoint = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f); // Center of the screen
}
```

**EDIT:**

I created a timer which sets the autoFocusPoint to the center every second... Now it seems to work, the object which is in the middle always seem to be in focus.

But doing it every X seconds seems to be bad, because when the view doesn't change, it shouldn't refocus, because it's already in focus.

Refocusing blurs everything for half a second before it gets focused again, so it's a bit bad user experience to have it every X seconds.

**So the question is: how do I know when should I refocus?**

I also found out that having a **null autoFocusPoint** should be my ideal solution:

> In order to disable use of the focus point and switch back to
> **continuous auto-focus mode**, the autoFocusPoint property should be set
> to null.

But then why didn't it have auto focus originally?

Could someone help me out please?

Comment: Can you tell if a QR code has successfully been detected? If so, that would be a good clue that you don't have to refocus again, right? So "as long as no QR code has been detected, keep trying to refocus periodically" would be the rule. Does that depart from what you need?

Comment: Yes, but once it detects a QR code (supposing that it's a QR code made for the app), the user is immediately transferred to another screen. So this method wouldn't really improve the experience of the scanning, sadly. Thanks though!

Comment: What's the imagined better experience that answers could strive toward? Let's walk through a scenario: we initialize the camera, and it starts trying to auto-focus. By the time the first auto-focus should have finished, we still don't have a valid QR code, so we try again. That auto-focus fails, so we try again. This third time, we detect the QR code and advance to the new screen. What other choice could the app have made in that scenario that would be better than "try again until success"?

Comment: I think the ideal solution would be to achieve a similiar experience to using just the Camera app of the phone. Which I think is best described as "continuous auto-focus mode". I don't know how it works. But I've just found out that it should be supported and that's the default mode: autoFocusPoint should be null and voilá. But for some reason it doesn't work.